# Удалить один эллемент массива js

Tags: javascript

```js
import data from '../../data.json';
import { ADD_IN_BASKET, REMOVE_IN_BASKET } from '../actions/productsActions'

const initialState = {
  products: data.razorBlades,
  basket:[],
};

export const productsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  switch(action.type){
    case ADD_IN_BASKET : return {
      products : [...state.products],
      basket: state.basket.concat({
      id: action.payload.id,
    })};
    case REMOVE_IN_BASKET: return {
      products: [...state.products],
      basket: state.basket.splice(
        state.basket.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload.id),
        1
      )
      
      // basket: state.basket.filter(product => product.id !== action.payload.id)
    }
    default: return state
  }
};
```

Есть массив. Нужно удалить только один эллемент по заданному id

```js
basket: basket.splice(basket.findIndex(item => item.id === selectedId),1) // мой вариант плохо работает, удаляет не то что нужно
basket: basket.filter(product => product.id !== selectedId) // удаляет все подходящие по ид,а нужно только один
```

```js
basket: [
      {
        id: 12
      },
      {
        id: 12
      },
      {
        id: 13
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Почему splice удаляет не то что нужно? Если что, splice _изменяет_ массив и возвращает вырезанные [Пример](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/oNLbVbR)

Comment: @Ein Не знаю почему, удаляет все сразу и один оставляет который не удаляется

Comment: Тогда это то о чём я написал. Вы присваиваете то что возвращает splice, а вам этого делать не нужно.

Comment: @Ein Мне наоборот нужно basket присвоить уже вырезанный массив

Comment: Ещё раз. `splice` изменяет массив, а не возвращяет новый, как например `map` или `filter`. [Почти тот же самый пример](https://codepen.io/loonybtard/pen/MWeKRjd). Т.е. нужно выполнить `splice` и после этого возвращать `basket`